# iOS constraint style: addConstraints vs .isActive = true

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have some code which is creating auto-layout constraints programatically, and adding them to a view.

There are two ways to do this - call `addConstraints` on the superView, or set `.isActive = true` on each constraint (which internally calls addConstraint)

Option 1:

```
parent.addConstraints([
    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    child.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leftAnchor, constant: 5) ])
```

Option 2:

```
child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
child.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

My question is, is there any benefit to doing one over the other? (performance/etc) or does it come purely down to style.

*(I don't think constraints are evaluated until the next layout pass, so I don't think it should matter that we add them one-by-one instead of in a block??)*

If it is just style, what's the "more preferred" style by the community??

*(personally I prefer addConstraints, however it's very close and I could be easily swayed to .isActive)*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the documentation on `addConstraint:` setting the `active` property is recommended for *individual constraints*. (note: `active` property is only available iOS 8+).

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s active
>   property to YES instead of calling the addConstraint: method directly.
>   The active property automatically adds and removes the constraint from
>   the correct view. ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint))

Also if you look at the interface definition for `addConstraint:` it has this comment:

> // This method will be deprecated in a future release and should be
>   avoided.  Instead, set NSLayoutConstraint's active property to YES

---

With that being said, there is actually a 3rd [and probably better] alternative, which is to use `NSLayoutConstraint`'s class method `activate:`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    child.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leftAnchor, constant: 5) ])
```

This is also a recommended solution according to the documentation and interface files. So if you have multiple constraints, this would be an easy solution and probably preferred in your situation.

(interface comment; emphasis mine):

> Convenience method that activates each constraint in the contained
>   array, in the same manner as setting active=YES. **This is often more
>   efficient than activating each constraint individually.**

Comment: Btw, it looks like "activateConstraints" has been renamed to "activate": https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I updated it. For future, feel free to just edit the answer yourself :D. Thanks again!